# angularjs alert message not coming properly

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-scope

when no dropdown is selected message comes but when any one or more dropdown is selected then also the message is coming Please select atleast one.Below is my angularjs

```
$scope.check = function () {


 if ($scope.landing.class == null || $scope.landing.class == undefined|| $scope.landing.class == "" && $scope.landing.fueltype == undefined || $scope.landing.fueltype == null || $scope.landing.fueltype == "" && $scope.landing.transmiss == null || $scope.landing.transmiss == undefined || $scope.transmiss == "" && $scope.landing.driving == null || $scope.landing.driving == undefined || $scope.driving == "" && $scope.landing.pick == null || $scope.landing.pick == undefined || $scope.landing.pick == "" && $scope.landing.stat == null || $scope.landing.stat == undefined || $scope.landing.stat == "") {
            alert('Please select atleast one')
        }
    }
```

Comment: *not coming properly*?

Comment: after selecting atleast one dropdown the message is coming it should not !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need extra parenthesis...

```
if (($scope.landing.class == null || $scope.landing.class == undefined || $scope.landing.class == "" )
&& (
$scope.landing.fueltype == undefined || $scope.landing.fueltype == null || $scope.landing.fueltype == "" )
&& (....
```

but in general this is ugly you must find a better/smarter way to do this validation..